# Difference between android:text="@string/hello" and normal right click--> Text view component--> EditText

Tags: java, android, android-layout

While I am working with help of tutorial I found this in textview android:text-"@string/hello" it shows some error.

Then I went through graphical view and right click the component and enter the text. Then that error removes and notifies me that

```
**Hardcoded string hello should use String resources**
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In android, "@string/" refer to the **string.xml** in **Project>res>values>** location in your package explorer.

String.xml contains a xml file which refer to a string with an id.
Eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World</string>
    <string name="app_name">My app</string>
</resources>
```

Here name="hello" is the id & "Hello World" is its value. When @string/hello is used, the value will be shown.

Similar is the case with "@drawable/". It will refer to the images used. and many more.

You can set text in text view programmatically. Eg:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);     //text1 is the id u provide in xml file
tv.setText("Hello World");
```

I hope it helped you.

Comment: I'm new to android programming and I might be wrong, so I write this as a comment. I think `@string/` is referred to all `<string></string>` tags in **all** XML files in **Project>res>values>**. I renamed 'strings.xml' to blablabla.xml, and it was still working.

Answer (score 1):

`@string/hello` simply notice Android to load the String in a XML file located into the /values directory (strings.xml).

`hello` is the ID of the String specified by `name="hello"` into that XML.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is very unstable. Previously, it auto generated the corresponding statement in the `string.xml` . Tutorials using previous versions get beginners stuck because of that.

### How `string.xml` works

Android Studio expects you to write all texts in one place, in the `string.xml` file. In all other files, you just put abbreviations. e.g.

```
android:text="@string/Hello_world"
```

means that find the abbreviation `Hello_world` in the `string.xml` file and replace it by the intended text.

In `string.xml`, the corresponding statement which should be written is:

```
<string name="Hello_world">Hello world!</string>
```

and that should do the job!

It is possible to just write `android:text="Hello world!"` (This is what hardcoding is). If you intend to be an android dev, then you would not maximize efficiency.

### Why? `string.xml`

Having all texts in one file eases many things. Like translation if needed and easy change. However, you should choose meaningful abbreviations!