# I get these 3 errors in eclipse (android hello world app)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

This is the code I pasted from one of android tutorials. However I get these 3 errors? Please help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is my first Android Application!" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="And this is a clickable button!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/hello').    main.xml    /Helloworld/res/layout  line 6  Android AAPT Problem`

`[I18N] Hardcoded string "And this is a clickable button!", should use @string resource  main.xml    /Helloworld/res/layout  line 17 Android Lint Problem`

`[I18N] Hardcoded string "This is my first Android Application!", should use @string resource    main.xml    /Helloworld/res/layout  line 13 Android Lint Problem`

Comment: did you check string.xml file in res--> values folder that it contains "hello" string or not for first error??

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the

```
<resources>
     <string name="hello">Hello World</string>
     <string name="app_name">My app</string>
</resources>
```

THe best bet would be to programmatically add the string:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);     //text1 is the id u provide in xml file
tv.setText("Hello World");
```

Here is more: 
[Difference between android:text="@string/hello" and normal right click--> Text view component--> EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278953/difference-between-androidtext-string-hello-and-normal-right-click-text-v)

Answer (score 1):

First one.  You have not defined the string "Hello" in strings.xml in res/values

```
<string name="hello">Hello!</string>
```

Two and three are warnings only.  You should not hard code strings in your layout.xmls because they cannot be localised.  You should use the same technique as "hello".

Answer (score 1):

try this,

String.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World</string>
    <string name="first_application">This is my first Android Application!</string>
    <string name="clickable_button">And this is a clickable button!</string>
</resources>
```

your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">
      <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello"/>
      <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/first_application"/>
      <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/clickable_button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`@string` refers to the xml file in your `res/values` folder called `strings.xml`, it should look something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Enter your "hello" text you want displayed here</string>
</resources>
```

The other errors are suggesting to create create strings for those as well, as I have above.